# 301 to extensionless page only if it exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If a user goes to:

```
www.example.com/mypage.asp
```

I want it to redirect to an extensionless version of the page:

```
www.example.com/mypage
```

But I only want to do it if the requested page exists, so:

`www.example.com/mypage.asp` -> 301 to -> `www.example.com/mypage`
But `www.example.com/notapage.asp` -> 404

How best to do this in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.asp[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` will make sure that it is done for a an existing file only.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: whereas RewriteRule (.*)\.asp$ $1 [NC,R=301] does (in it's simplest form).  It seems like the -f condition in your example isn't detecting the existing file properly.

Comment: Can you try `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.asp -f` instead of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f`. What is your apache version?